# Excel autofill problem with different rows

Tags: excel

I am working on an excel project where I have to fill all  the blank with info but it differs every some rows looks like this

[image]

***and this is what I would like to achieve.***

[image]

Comment: Please can you show what you have tried so far and what specific piece of code is not working? See http://whathaveyoutried.com/ for an example on what you can add to your question

Comment: Non-programmatic questions about using Excel should be asked over on [Super User](https://superuser.com/), and aren't generally [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Do you want to use VBA to automate this? Have you attempted anything already? Why are there still blanks in the second screenshot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow below steps.

- Select cells you want to fill up.
- From ***Home*** tab--> ***Editing*** section select ***Find & Select*** then ***Go To Special***.
- Select ***Blanks*** and click ok.
- Now just type `=Immediate above cell address you want to fill` like `=A1`.
- Then press <kbd>CTRL+ENTER</kbd>. Blanks cells should fill up with data from its above cell.
- If you wish to remove formulas from cells then copy all cells in range and right click then ***paste values***.

[image]